# window.alert cannot be deleted

Tags: javascript

I was reading about JavaScript delete operator and experimenting on it. everything seems fine until I tried to delete a method from the window object. the code looks like following

```
var log = function(str){
  if(str !== undefined)
  {
    document.write(str);
  }
   document.write("</br>");
};


window.myVar = function(){
  // do something
};

// this deletes custom method 
log(delete  window.myVar);  // true (expected)
log(typeof window.myVar);  // undefined (expected)

log(delete window.alert);  // true (OK)
log(typeof window.alert); // function (Unexpected)

window.alert = 10;
log(typeof window.alert);   // number (Successfully overwritten)
log(delete window.alert);  // true
log(typeof window.alert); // function (Returns back to original object)
```

It seems that it lets me delete objects I created but not the objects already defined but it is letting me override it. Can anybody explain me what is the reason behind it? Also delete should return 'false' if it fails to delete an object which is also not happening here.

[Update] I am using FF 19 and running it in http://jsbin.com

**[Update]** Note that I understand how to override window.alert and run my custom code. My question is what is so special about window.alert that it cannot be deleted yet the delete returns true? I know it is a native object but that does not explain why this is not possible. Is it the browser JavaScript engine re-add the alert method after it is deleted by my code?. Also is it possible for me to write similar kind of function that another user using my library cannot delete but only override? How?

Comment: Native functions cannot be deleted. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I understand it should not be done in actual code but here I am trying to learn technically exactly what is going on and if it is using some JavaScript feature what are those features and if it is possible to use those features in custom code/library

Answer (score 1):

Simple, we can overwrite existing functions but not erase them. Existing/Standard functions are reset to the standard prototype instead when delete invoked on it. But if you do like to neutralise the function say windows.alert then assign a blank function like below:

```
window.alert = function(){}; //blank function makes window.alert now useless
```

Try a console (Browser) based script:

```
window.alert = function(data){
    console.log('alerting:'+data)
}; 
window.alert('hi'); // this will print "alerting:hi" in console
delete window.alert
window.alert('hi'); // now this will show regular alert message box with "hi" in it
```

I hope this explains it.

UPDATE:

Lets say you want to overwrite a Standard Function "alert" then:

```
//this function will append the data recieved to a HTML element with 
// ID message-div instead of showing browser alert popup
window.alert = function(data){
    document.getElementById('message-div').innerHTML = data;
}
alert('Saved Successfully'); //usage as usual
...
//when you no longer need custom alert then you revert to standard with statement below
delete window.alert;
```

Comment: And why `log(delete window.alert);  // returns true`?

Comment: it returns true as delete for functions like alert reverts it to default state.

Comment: "we can overwrite existing functions but not erase them" - Technically how this is done? Is it using some exposed JavaScript way of doing this? In that case can I use this in my custom code?